# Android app automatic app update

Tags: android-update-app

I have a question and I don't know what I'm missing that it is working. My problem is that my published application is not consider for automatic updates through google play store. I also found that some other not from me are not consider for an automatic update while a new version is in the play store.

How can I achieve that my application will be updated automatically?

The playstore will show the user that there is a new version (Upgrade button is visible) but the application is not being updated automatically :/

Comment: Theres nothing you can change about this! User decide if they wanna recieve automatic updates or not.

Comment: Yes ok but then tell me please. How can I decide if I want automatic updates for one app an not for the other, because I receive automatic updates for Facebook but not for my application and I never set up something that I want automatic updates for Facebook and not for my application

Comment: You can change this in the play store settings. It seems to me that facebook offers "in-app-update-notifications" which you then click on to recieve updates.

Comment: It's not only by facebook also other applications are updating them self through google play store without explicitly set from myself to do an update while a new version is available. So it seems that there should something be done from the my side to automatic update my application when google play store sees that a new version is available. But what is this?